# Cannot invoke add on the array type

Tags: java, arrays

I have been given some code to tinker with, which is a prisoners dilema game are initially the players were set with this piece of code into an array.

```
IPDPlayer[] currentPlayers = { new RandomPlayer(),  
                                    new TFTPlayer(),  new TFTPlayer(), new TFTPlayer(), 
                                    new CoopPlayer(), new CoopPlayer(), new CoopPlayer(),
                                    new UncoopPlayer(), new UncoopPlayer(), new UncoopPlayer()};
```

I'm  trying to replace this with:

```
IPDPlayer[] currentPlayers = {};
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" How many Tit-for-Tat?");
int in_value = sc1.nextInt();
for(int x = 0; x < in_value; x++)
{
    currentPlayers.add(new TFTPlayer());
}
```

As a way of choosing the number and type of players once the program has begun. However I simply get the error 
"Cannot invoke add(TFTPlayer) on the array type IPDPlayer[]"

Comment: the add method is there for Collections, but an Array is not a Collection.

Comment: Array in java doesn't have any methods other than the methods inherited from Object class. `add` method is from `Collection` interface and Array doesn't come under that hierarchy. You need to use actual indices like `currentPlayers[x] = new TFTPlayer()` or you can change your code to use some collection implementation like `ArrayList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [JLS 10.2. Array Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) and  [JLS 10.6. Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> The length of the array to be constructed is equal to the number of variable initializers immediately enclosed by the braces of the array initializer. Space is allocated for a new array of that length. If there is insufficient space to allocate the array, evaluation of the array initializer completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError. Otherwise, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

You are initializing an array with size 0,and you are accessing array in wrong way, you have to give the size of array while declaring it like:

```
IPDPlayer[] currentPlayers = new IPDPlayer[sizeOfArray];
```

---

Better use `ArrayList` for Your job like:

```
List<IPDPlayer> currentPlayers = new ArrayList<IPDPlayer>();
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" How many Tit-for-Tat?");
int in_value = sc1.nextInt();
for(int x = 0; x < in_value; x++)
{
    currentPlayers.add(new TFTPlayer());
}
```

And if you want to return array from List use below code:

```
currentPlayers.toArray(new IPDPlayer[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have an array right at the very beginning; Use a list and once the input is over, you can always convert it to an array .

```
List<IPDPlayer> ipdPlayerLst = new ArrayList<IPDPlayer>();
ipdPlayerLst .add(.....);
```

later

```
IPDPlayer[] currentPlayers = new IPDPlayer[ipdPlayerLst .size()];
currentPlayers =ipdPlayerLst.toArray(currentPlayers );
```

Comment: I think this line is wrong -  `ipdPlayerLst.toArray(ipdPlayerLst); ` It should be `ipdPlayerLst.toArray(currentPlayers);`. Overloaded version of `toArray()` takes an array reference not a list :)